# "ssh: Could not resolve hostname \342\200\223" for command line 'ssh -T git@github.com'

Tags: bash, git, github, ssh

I am receiving:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname \342\200\223t: Name or service not known

for

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Keygen has been added to GitHub and they were tested to match using

```
ssh-add -l -E md5
```

They do match, but I am still receiving this error.

I also tried:

```
ping github.com
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

This was a suggested fix on another question that didn't work. The ping returns an IP address, so the connection seems to be working. Also Git pull works, but it requires a password each time. It’s a hostname error, so does it have to do with the DNS? Or maybe a port needs to be forwarded.

Comment: Hi Casey, welcome to Stackoverflow. What was the suggested fix on the other thread you mentioned? Do you have a link?

Comment: A similar problem with strange characters (e.g, [POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8230&number=128) (U+202A)) on the command-line: *[How to solve error message "gcc‬: command not found" (only with arguments) on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61725948/)*. Where is the canonical question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using the wrong hyphen character `-` somewhere. `\342\200\223` is UTF-8 for U+2013 EN DASH, which looks like `–`. It is possible that this is due to autocorrect, a filter set up somewhere on a blog, or copying and pasting things. I know that when I type on my iPhone, if I type `--` (two hyphens) it will get changed to `–` (one en dash) by the phone automatically, which makes it deeply frustrating to answer Stack Overflow questions.

So, `–` is incorrect, but `-` is correct. Welcome to the world of Unicode. Notice that the en dash is slightly... but just slightly... longer.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is definitely useful information. I had no clue unicode changed hyphens on browsers and apps. That makes sense though because so many different systems need to see the same thing. So from now on no copy pasting! Thank you!!!