# How to solve error message "gcc‬: command not found" (only with arguments) on Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation

I am working with [Ubuntu 19.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.04_(Disco_Dingo)) (Disco Dingo), and I have GCC installed.

When I run

```
gcc
```

I am getting an error showing that I do have `gcc`:

> gcc: fatal error: no input files compilation terminated.

When I am running `gcc` with arguments like this

```
gcc‬‬ ‫‪-g‬‬ ‫‪-m32‬‬ ‫‪-o‬‬ ‫‪skip‬‬ ‫‪skip.c‬‬
```

I am getting

> gcc‬‬: command not found

I've ran

```
apt-get purge gcc
apt-get install build-essential
```

And still I am getting the same error.

Comment: @usr installing build-essentials installs gcc, I specifically write that just gcc is working, please read the OP

Comment: regarding: `apt-get purge gcc` and `apt-get install build-essential`  Unless you running as `root`, (which is a very bad idea) these command will not work.  Suggest using the `sudo` command prefixed to each of those commands.  Note: the first thing that will happen is the `sudo` will request  your password.

Comment: suggest, at a command prompt, running: `set | more` to see if there is some environment  variable that is messing up the usage of the `gcc` command

Comment: A more direct analysis of the problem with the invisible characters is (e.g., from the output of `hexdump -e '"%08.8_ax " 8/1 "%02X " " " 8/1 "%02X " " |"' -e '16/1 "%_p""|\n"' '/home/mortensen/temp2/2022-05-08/Broken GCC characters.txt'`), 0xE2 0x80 0xAC (hexadecimal), reveals UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+200C ([POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8704&number=128)). Similarly, there are also RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING (U+202B) and LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING (U+202A) in there.

Comment: Instead of cumbersome analysis, the most common ones can be searched for in a reasonable modern text editor in ***regular expression mode*** with `\x{00A0}|\x{200B}|\x{200C}|\x{2013}|\x{2014}|\x{201C}|\x{201D}|\x{2212}|\x{00E4}|\x{FFFD}|\x{2217}|\x{200C}|\x{202B}|\x{202A}`. Using search-replace, even the ***invisible*** ones can be fixed (deleted or replaced with space)—there isn't any need to retype anything. The check could even be added to compilation, make, or [automatic build system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration#Deploy_an_artefact_from_CI) steps.

Comment: The underlying reason for this problem is copy-paste of ***formatted text***, e.g., from web sites (like [blogposts](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blogpost#Noun)), [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents, or chat sessions (e.g., [Skype Chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#Skype_chat)). Related Stack Overflow question (canonical): *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*

Comment: This can't be the first question of this nature (invisible Unicode characters messing up command-line invocations). Where is the *canonical* question? Here is [one from 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52322629/having-an-issue-with-ssh-t-gitgithub-com), but there *must* be some much older ones. One way to find candidates is to search for the octal sequences (often part of error messages), e.g. "`site:stackoverflow.com 342 200 213`". Sometimes the numbers are in hexadecimal (E2 80 8B) or decimal (226 128 139).

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
gcc‬‬ ‫‪-g‬‬ ‫‪-m32‬‬ ‫‪-o‬‬ ‫‪skip‬‬ ‫‪skip.c
```

is ASCII broken. There are strange (invisible) characters before the spaces. Check it [here](https://ideone.com/IJUuP9).

Also, to run `gcc` with `-m32` flag on, you need to install `gcc-multilib` first:

```
apt-get install gcc-multilib
```

Comment: I installed it and still get the same gcc not found error

Comment: Yes, because you are copy-pasting the broken line, try to write the line `gcc -g -m32 -o skip skip.c` from scratch without copying it.

Comment: WoW that's an improvement, but still getting this gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-m32‫‪’ after installing what you suggested

Comment: Ok, now install `gcc-multilib`, as I say in my answer :P

Comment: Look at the comment, After installing it. Still getting that error

Comment: Wow, it's strange, are you on an arm plattform? I think m32 is not available on this architecture

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is happening. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 (amd64) and I'm able to compile with `-m32` flag on after installing `gcc-multilib`.

Comment: `gcc-multilib` not installed would result in a different error (something about libraries not found). This must be a non-amd64 platform.